# How can i compare a DataFrame with other DataFrame's columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different DataFrame's. `df` is the complete one and `sample` is for the comparing. Here is the data i have:

```
sample.tail()
   T1  C   C1   C2   C3
0   1  5  0.0  7.0  5.0

df.tail()
   T1  T2  C   C1   C2   C3
0   1   0  5  4.0  6.0  6.0
1   0   0  5  5.0  4.0  6.0
2   0   1  7  5.0  5.0  4.0
3   1   1  0  7.0  5.0  5.0
4   1   1  5  0.0  7.0  5.0
```

I have selected some columns from `sample` df and trying to find values in `df` matches the `sample`

Here what i did so far but no luck:

```
cols = sample.columns
df = df[df[cols] == sample[cols]]
```

and i am getting the following error:

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Can you kindly help me to findout the solution for this?

EDIT: Expected output

```
df.tail()
   T1  T2  C   C1   C2   C3
0   1   0  5  0.0  7.0  5.0
21  1   1  5  0.0  7.0  5.0
27  1   0  5  0.0  7.0  5.0
34  1   1  5  0.0  7.0  5.0
42  1   1  5  0.0  7.0  5.0
47  1   0  5  0.0  7.0  5.0
51  1   1  5  0.0  7.0  5.0
```

You can see that All data matches with sample dataframe except T2. This is expected output for me

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what are you trying to do.. Calculate the *intersection of column names*, i.e. what are the common columns? Or check if values in columns are the same? What do you expect as output for your example?

Comment: Actually i am trying to select all values from df that matches values of sample. Ignoring T2. In this case i would like to compare T1,C,C1,C2,C3

Comment: The title of the question is comparing a DataFrame with another one's columns. If the intent is different, please edit the title and question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`pd.Index.intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html), you can use

```
cols = sample.columns.intersection(df.columns)
df[df[cols].apply(tuple, axis=1).isin(sample[cols].apply(tuple, axis=1))]
```

Comment: i have edited the question and added expected output

Comment: this gives me the same error: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Comment: @DonCoder Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly the one i was looking for